# Dim and Blur Background Behind Fragment Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So I have a custom "dialog" of sorts, it's really just a fragment inside a framelayout.
Anyway, I want it to blur and dim the anything that is behind it once its displayed.
I am currently using this, inside the onCreateView

```
  // Dim and blur background
    getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
    getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);
```

However, this is not blurring or dimming the other framelayout which contains a RecyclerView and a CardView, these elements are still being shown in full opacity, not sure why?

Here is a screeshot, as you can see the background gets blurred but not all the views behind the fragment get dimmed

[image]

I'd like to be able to achieve the look that NavigationDrawer has when you open it, here is an example inside the same app and everything is being dimmed and blurred correctly.

[image]

Here is my XML file incase it helps,

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".controllers.MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/app_bar_main_layout">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

 // This is the framelayout for a fragment
 // The fragment contains a RecyclerView and a CardView
 // This is what I would like to be dimmed.
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/frame_layout_container"
    android:background="@color/colorCardDisplayBackground"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
</FrameLayout>


 // This is my custom "Dialog" fragment
<FrameLayout
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/card_fragment_container">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button_background"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_done_white_24dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/final_confirm_card_button"/>
</FrameLayout>

<com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/mainFab"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    fab:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_add_white_48dp"
    fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorAccent"
    fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/colorAccentLight"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end" />
```

Comment: @DanielNugent, thats not a possible solution, and not actually a fix to this problem.

Comment: The fact is, a DialogFragment is what the Android framework provides in order to easily do exactly what you're trying to do.  You can implement all of the same functionality in a DialogFragment that you could in any other Fragment, and the background will be dimmed and blurred in the standard way.  If the architecture of your project prevents you from using a DialogFragment, so be it, but if you can use it, it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the comment the `FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND` was not working with the frame layout I was using.

I instead decided to just change the foreground of the parent

```
// Dim the background
// Where mainFrameLayout is as FrameLayout
mainFrameLayout.getForeground().setAlpha(220);
```

And when you would like to remove the "dim" effect

```
// Remove dim background color
mainFrameLayout.getForeground().setAlpha(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND` flag has been deprecated since API 14, so you shouldn't expect it to work.

Unfortunately, Android did not provide a built-in alternative when they deprecated this flag. However, there are several alternative solutions that have been developed. I would recommend taking a look at the 500px blur library described [here](http://developers.500px.com/2015/03/17/a-blurring-view-for-android.html).

The idea behind this view is that you call `.setBlurredView(View view)`, with `view` being the view below the `BlurringView` that is to be blurred. Then, call `.invalidate()` whenever the blur is to be redrawn since the view to blur changed. Note that this blurring effect makes use of the `RenderScript` `ScriptIntrinsicBlur` effect.

Comment: Will take a look at this since it looks interesting, however DIM_BEHIND is not depreciated, and it still is not dimming the views behind my fragment, which is odd?

Comment: I haven't used that flag before, but with the approach described above, you can also apply a dim. The `RenderScript` `ScriptIntrinsicBlur` takes a `Bitmap` and returns a blurred `Bitmap`. You can then make a new bitmap from the blurred one with every pixel dimmed by a certain amount.

Comment: Just looked at the library you mentioned and it doesn't work with RecyclerViews according to github and I couldn't get it to work, so sadly that wont fix it for me.

Comment: This solution would've worked for me if i wasnt using a RecyclerView, the way I fixed it for my issues, was adding a foreground drawable (black color) and change the alpha to > 0 whenever I want to dim that certain view.